# My modal container for confirmation closes right after submiting

Tags: javascript

I hope you can help me with this doubt that is taking me days to solve (I'm a junior developer still learning xD). I have a modal with a simple Ok button to show after add the data to my json-server database. But the modal appears so fast that user don't have the time to click the ok button to be redirected to the homepage. After the modal closes it stays in the same page and is not redirected to homepage.

```
//Email and password validation
const validateEmail = (email) => {
  const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
  return emailRegex.test(email);
};

let duplicatedEmail = false;

const checkData = (email) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (
      newUserName.value.trim() === "" ||
      newUserEmail.value.trim() === "" ||
      newUserPassword.value.trim() === "" ||
      newUserAddress.value.trim() === "" ||
      newUserPC.value.trim() === "" ||
      newUserCountry.value.trim() === ""
    ) {
      otherAlerts.classList.add("otherAlertsActive");
      otherAlerts.innerHTML =
        "Please fill all the register info.";
      reject();
      return;
    }

    fetch("http://localhost:3000/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        for (let userI = 0; userI < data.length; userI++) {
          if (data[userI].email === email) {
            duplicatedEmail = true;
            otherAlerts.classList.add("otherAlertsActive");
            otherAlerts.innerHTML =
              "Email already registered!";
            newUserEmail.value = "";
            return reject(new Error("Duplicated email"));
          }
        }
        if (!duplicatedEmail) {
          if (newUserPassword.value === newUserPasswordCheck.value) {
            const regexSenha =
              /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*]{8,}$/;
            if (regexSenha.test(newUserPassword.value) === false) {
              newUserPassword.value = "";
              otherAlerts.classList.add("otherAlertsActive");
              otherAlerts.innerHTML =
                "Password should contain at least 1 upper case, 1 lower case and 1 symbol";
            }
          } else {
            otherAlerts.classList.add("otherAlertsActive");
            otherAlerts.innerHTML =
              "The two passwords don't match";
          }
        }
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};

// Form submission, modal with button "ok" and link to homepage

const redirectHomepage = () => {
  window.location.href = "index.html";
};

submitNewUser.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  duplicatedEmail = false;

  if (!validateEmail(newUserEmail.value)) {
    otherAlerts.classList.add("otherAlertsActive");
    otherAlerts.innerHTML = "Email with incorrect format!";
    return;
  }

  checkData(newUserEmail.value).then(() => {
    if (duplicatedEmail) {
      return Promise.reject(
        new Error("Email already registered!")
      );
    }

    if (newUserPassword.value !== newUserPasswordCheck.value) {
      return Promise.reject(
        new Error("The two passwords do not match")
      );
    }

    const regexSenha =
      /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*]{8,}$/;
    if (!regexSenha.test(newUserPassword.value)) {
      return Promise.reject(
        new Error(
          "Password should contain at least 1 upper case, 1 lower case and 1 symbol"
        )
      );
    }
    let name = newUserName.value;
    let email = newUserEmail.value;
    let password = newUserPassword.value;
    let address = newUserAddress.value;
    let pc = newUserPC.value;
    let country = newUserCountry.value;
    let active = "não";
    let newData = {
      nome: name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      morada: address,
      "código postal": pc,
      país: country,
      activo: active,
    };
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/users", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(newData),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        modal.style.display = "flex";
        const modalCloseButton = document.getElementById("modal-close-button");
        modalCloseButton.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
          redirectHomepage();
        });
        console.log("Data successfully sent: ", response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error send data: ", error);
      });
  });
});
```

Can you please detect any error in my code? I'm sure I'm doing something wrong :/

Thank you all

Comment: Is **submitNewUser** a button with no type or with the type of submit?